# What is the figure of speech here?

Tags: figurative-language, rhetoric

Dictionary.com defines **celluloid** as

> of or involving motion pictures

*The boots have been immortalised on *celluloid* in her latest film, Strictly Sinatra, directed by Peter Capaldi.*

[Lexico]

I was wondering if this constitutes some figure of speech?

Comment: Do you have any example in which it is used?

Comment: @user178049: I've added an example in the question itself. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is **metonymy**

/mɪˈtɒnɪmi/

> the substitution of the name of an attribute or adjunct for that of the thing meant, for example *suit* for business executive, or the *turf* for horse racing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will synecdoche work too? @James K?

Comment: Yes,and there are ambiguous boundries between the two.